# "$centerSphere" query in reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, geospatial, latitude-longitude, reactivemongo

I found [click here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/centerSphere/#op._S_centerSphere) here and

I want to do "2d" indexing in `reactivemongo` and then want to use following query in `reactivemongo`

```
db.collName.find({
    loc: {
    $geoWithin: {
        $centerSphere: [
            [lng, lat], radius / 6371
        ]
    }
    }
})
```

How to implement it in reactivemongo?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactivemongo this query would look like this:

```
def findNear(lng: Double, lat: Double, radius: Double)(implicit fomrat: Format[T], ec: ExecutionContext): Enumerator[T] = {
        collection().
            find(Json.obj("loc" -> Json.obj("$geoWithin" -> Json.obj("$centerSphere" -> Json.arr(Json.arr(lng, lat), JsNumber(radius / 6371)))))).
            cursor[T].
            enumerate()
    }
```

I've played with simple case class, to test this:

```
case class Company(name: String, loc: Point)

case class Point(lon: Double, lat: Double)

object Company extends MongoCollection[Company] {

    implicit val pointFormat: Format[Point]  = Json.format[Point]
    implicit val companyFormat: Format[Company] = Json.format[Company]

    val collectionName = "company"

    def findNear(lng: Double, lat: Double, radius: Double)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Enumerator[Company] = {
        collection().
            find(Json.obj("loc" -> Json.obj("$geoWithin" -> Json.obj("$centerSphere" -> Json.arr(Json.arr(lng, lat), JsNumber(radius / 6371)))))).
            cursor[Company].
            enumerate()
    }

}
```

and test

```
object CompanySpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions {

    sequential

    "geo spatial" should {

        val A = Company("A", Point(0, 0))
        val B = Company("B", Point(0, 1))
        val C = Company("C", Point(1, 1))
        val D = Company("D", Point(1, 0))

        Company.saveAll(List(A, B, C, D)).await()

        "return A " in {
            Company.findNear(0, 0, 1).collect().await() shouldEqual List(A)
        }

        "return A, B, C" in {

            Company.findNear(0, 0, 120).collect().await() shouldEqual List(A, B, D)
        }

        "return D" in {
            Company.findNear(0, 0, 240).collect().await() shouldEqual List(A, B, C, D)
        }

    }

}
```